# How to visit an array indexed by indexed in php / Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api

I got an API response like

> `["at123@gmail.com","adhd5@gmail.com","adahsad5@gmail.com"]`

I got this array in a request variable **$request->optional_email** I am trying to access data by a loop like below:

```php
foreach ($request->optional_email as $key => $optionalEmail) {
    $email->email = $optionalEmail[$key];
    $email->save();
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I solve it?

Comment: The syntax is not correct. It should be either `$email->email = $optionalEmail` or  `$email->email = $request->optional_email[$key];`.

Comment: I try these, but it insert only last email

Comment: Thanks @IGP I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the $request->optional_email is just a list you do not need to use the $key variable in the foreach.
Instead you should just use the value ($optionalEmail) of the foreach so your code would look something like this:

```php
foreach ($request->optional_email as $optionalEmail) {
    $email->email = $optionalEmail;
    $email->save();
}
```

Comment: I try it, but it insert only last email

Comment: Thanks @BI00D4NGEL. I got it!!